# what's means of the sysctl_apply in rpm's spec

Tags: post, rpm, specifications

rpm spec

```
%post
%sysctl_apply openstack-keystone.conf
```

What is the meaning of sysctl_apply?  Where can I find this document?

Answer (score 2):

Lets expand it:

```
$ rpm --eval '%sysctl_apply foo'
/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl foo >/dev/null 2>&1 || :
```

Now see `man systemd-sysctl` for more informations and you will learn that is sets kernel parameters using `sysctl`.

For more informations and similar macros see: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines#binfmt.d.2C_sysctl.d_and_tmpfiles.d